# I want to return '1' as a default value in oracle when the below query or conditions returns no rows

Tags: database, oracle

```
SELECT el_values_field3 
from data_form_values_1125505 
where el_values_field2=city
```

city is the input parameter here

Answer (score 0):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3e91/21)

```
SELECT COALESCE(T."city", 1) as City
FROM dual
LEFT JOIN (Select *
           FROM Table1
           WHERE "city" = 3) T
   ON T."city" > 0;
```

**OUTPUT** when find the city = 2

```
| CITY |
|------|
|    2 |
|    2 |
|    2 |
```

**OUTPUT** when doesnt find it

```
| CITY |
|------|
|    1 |
```

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(T.el_values_field3, 1) as City FROM dual LEFT JOIN (Select * FROM data_form_values_1125505 WHERE el_values_field2=city) T ON T.el_values_field2> 0

Comment: What mean doesnt work? You can update the sql fiddle to include your table and I take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
select nvl((
SELECT el_values_field3 
from data_form_values_1125505 
where el_values_field2=city
), 1) from dual
```

Comment: That doesnt works if query return more than one value

Comment: Yes true, your answer is better. :-)